# can not connect to oracle database using php

Tags: php, oracle

I am using XAMPP version 5.6.15 to run my PHP file on windows 10.

But I am getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in F:\xampp\htdocs\Sbank\index.php on line 4

According to PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) everything should work fine.

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('admin', 'admin', 'localhost/JDT');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT sysdate FROM dual');
oci_execute($stid);

echo $stid;


?>
```

Comment: Is the OCI8 extension enabled?

Comment: @Fairy I removed the ; before the extension=php_oci8_11g.dll within  php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you have OCI8 extension enabled.
check output of `phpinfo()` or `extension_loaded ('extension name')`
or in CLI `php -m`

Comment: I removed the ; before the extension=php_oci8_11g.dll within php.ini file and at phpinfo() the page is loaded but i dont really understand what do i hvae to check please ?

Comment: Once you have enabled extension (removed `;` before extension name in `php.ini`) restart apache and try run you script.

Comment: same error Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Comment: Please see [Installing OCI8 on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php) section for details, hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help ill check again in hope to find out what the problem >

Comment: i followed that link too but nothing helped 
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm

Answer (score 1):

If instant client has been installed but the full oracle client
not yet ,you can use pdo to connect to oracle database
like following coding:

```
<?php
$tns = " 
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = yourip)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
       ";
$db_username = "youname";
$db_password = "yourpassword";
try{
    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns,$db_username,$db_password);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

Comment: I tried to use your code instead of my and i got error message said could not find driver

Comment: then try this https://me2learn.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/connect-php-with-oracle-database/

Comment: does it apply to xampp Apache server ?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by following details steps within below youtube.com tutorial

[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdWWnPC4xzs)